# clearing app pages from device background logging out automatically titanium studio

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules

After login into App my App running fine in background mode But after If I clear App from background mode it automatically logged out from App. But i want it should be logged in until user manually logged out from App. How i can make it possible ?

My code:

```
results = {
                    iuser_id: response.iuser_id,
                    signup_ids: response.signup_ids,
                    staff_id : response.staff_id,           
                    vusername: response.vusername,
                    vfirst_name: response.vfirst_name,
                    vlast_name: response.vlast_name,
                    vemail : response.vemail,
                    vpwd : response.vpwd
                    };  
                Ti.App.Properties.setObject("user_session",results);
                results = null;
                var flag = '';

                if (!Ti.App.Properties.hasProperty('installed')) 
                {
                    Ti.App.Properties.setBool('app:isLoggedIn', true);
                    Ti.App.Properties.hasProperty('installed');
                    Ti.App.Properties.setBool('installed', true);
                    var th_sign = Alloy.createController('login').getView();
                    th_sign.open();
                }
                else
                {

                    var th_sign = Alloy.createController('home').getView();
                    th_sign.open();
                }
                }
```

Comment: Please share some code. how does user logs in? do you call a website? is a session created do you do the following webservice calls with a token? do you save this token or do you keep it in a singleton?

Comment: user will be log in into App by based on response of JSON with creating session data as well as by checking properties of app is  installed or uninstalled in device. I put code above in my previous comment